# Silverstripe Migration To Https Error

Tags: php, http, silverstripe

After finishing a website using Silverstripe CMS(3.5.6) I migrated it via GIT to another server that is using HTTPS. My server is using HTTP. After the migrate, it doesn't load my css and js files.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="$BaseHref$ThemeDir/assets/css/example.css"/>
```

and it displays the following line:

```
http://website.com/themes/the_theme/assets/css/example.css
```

It should display HTTPS://... not HTTP://...

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `<% base_tag %>` in your theme, you don't need to have `$BaseHref` in your stylesheet link.

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="$ThemeDir/assets/css/example.css"/>`

This is how i've done it previously and it will work in both a http and https environment.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. This version you just typed didn't work at first, but afterwards I found something in my .htacces that was forcing http, don't know why. I just commented that out and now everything works fine.

Comment: No worries. Glad you have sorted it out :)